Strange usage of chain rule. Can anyone explain why this derivation was done this way?

There are 2 issues I have with the way this was done. The first was how chain rule was used in the (1.35), and the second was how chain rule was used in (1.36). It all seems so counterintuitive.
For (1.35), to start I tried plugging for the initial equation, but without known values for $\delta p$, I can't use it to verify this equation. So, I attempted to obtain it using chain rule, and doesn't make a lot of sense the way I'm assuming it was done. Unless I'm just blatantly abusing chain rule, this result just doesn't seem possible. Trying to do this a bit more intuitively:

Transform 1: $p(x,z) = g(x,z) \therefore z = z(x,z)$ (pretty sure we can't do this)

$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial g}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$$
It's my understanding that we could also abuse chain rule here and say $\frac{\partial a_i}{\partial n_i}\frac{\partial n_i}{\partial k_i} = \frac{\partial a_i}{\partial k_i}$, otherwise we're saying that z is a function of x when it just plainly isn't. When and Why would we choose to abuse chain rule like this?

Drop the functions to get a definition for the differential operator

$$\tag{1}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}  = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$$

Second transformation: $p(x,z) = h(x,s) \therefore s = s(x,z)$ (THIS would be a proper usage of transforming a variable and then applying chain rule, but why do it here rather than at the beginning?)

$$\frac{\partial h}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial h}{\partial s}\frac{\partial s}{\partial z}$$

Drop the functions to get a differential operator to substitute into (1)

$$\tag{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial s}{\partial z}\frac{\partial}{\partial s}$$
And then plugging in (2) into (1) and applying the derivative to the original function $p$ would give:
$$\tag{5} \frac{\partial p}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial p}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial s}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial p}{\partial s}$$
I have no idea why we couldn't have just instead done $p(x,z) = g(x,s) \therefore s = s(x,z)$ at the very beginning and then done $\frac{\partial p}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial p}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial p}{\partial s}\frac{\partial s}{\partial x}$, nor do I understand why this would be incorrect whereas we would consider (1.36) correct. Does anyone understand why it was done this way?

(1.35) seems primarily motivated by geometry; if you follow their logic of $\delta x$ and look at the attached picture, it makes sense why they're doing it the way they did.
If you want to explicitly use the chain rule instead, you can note that the multivariate chain rule states (as a differential form)$$dp=\frac{\partial p}{\partial z}dz+\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}dx$$
and then explicitly as a partial derivative along the contour where $s$ is constant:
$$\frac{\partial p(x,s)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial p(x,z)}{\partial z}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)_s+\frac{\partial p(x,z)}{\partial x}$$
which is (1.35), understanding that the $p(x,s)$ on the LHS is different from the $p(x,z)$ on the RHS, as you've essentially replaced $z$ with $s$ as the "vertical" variable. Crucially the LHS term is because on the constant-$s$ contour, the total derivative $dp$ is a function of $x$ only.
Then (1.36) is just substituting out the $\frac{\partial p(x,z)}{\partial z}$ term with $\frac{\partial p(x,s)}{\partial s}\frac{\partial s}{\partial z}$, a direct application of the chain rule on a contour where $x$ is constant.

would the partial differential instead be $$\partial p(x,z) = \frac{\partial p}{\partial z}\partial z + \frac{\partial p}{\partial x}\partial x$$, and the second equation would be $\frac{\partial p(x,z)}{\partial x}$ because based on the RHS, it doesn't like we've transformed the variable from z to s coordinates yet? I think the transform to s coordinates only came when we performed $\frac{\partial p}{\partial y}$, and then after plugging that result in, I think it would technically be $p(x,s)$ at that point. Not sure though

The LHS $dp$ is the total derivative and is coordinate-independent/agnostic (note also the use of $d$ not $\partial$ as a piece of suggestive notation). However, on the next line where we've differentiated with respect to $x$, it's explicit that the total derivative of $p$ is specifically along a constant-$s$ contour, so we explicitly specify the coordinates as $(x,s)$ on the LHS. Meanwhile, the RHS is consistently in $(x,z)$ coordinates.

Then I don't understand how chain rule works when a variable is held constant i.e. a derivative along the constant surface. We were originally in the coordinates of $p = p(x,z)$ and then transformed to $p = p(x,s(x,z))$ so via chain rule I would expect $$\frac{dp}{dx} = \frac{dp}{dx} + \frac{dp}{ds}\frac{ds}{dx}$$, what did the steps become for this instead with the condition that it's along a constant surface? Say it was $$(\frac{dp}{dx})_z$$ and we had still transformed the vertical coordinate to s, what generally would be the approach?

I just realized taking from your idea of writing out the total differential that (if my notation is right) $$dp(x,s) = \frac{\partial p}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial p}{\partial s}\frac{\partial s}{\partial z}dz$$ so if we took $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ of both sides, we'd also obtain: $$\frac{\partial p}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial p}{\partial x}+ \frac{\partial s}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial s}\frac{\partial p}{\partial s}$$. Would that also work? Also probably ignore my last question, I should make a separate post about chain rule and constant surfaces. Thanks for the help!

The partial derivative operator, when there is a coordinate transformation from $u$ to $\bar{u}$, is given by $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{u}^i}=\sum_j\frac{\partial u^j}{\partial \bar{u}^i}\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{u}^j}$$So the RHS of your previous comment with $$\frac{\partial p(x,s)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial p(x,z)}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial p(x,s)}{\partial s}\frac{\partial s}{\partial x}$$isn't correct. And it should make sense why it's incorrect; on the LHS you're keeping $s$ constant while taking the partial derivative w.r.t $x$, so there shouldn't be $ds$ terms on the RHS

So let's say we want to transform a Cartesian function $f(x,y,z)$ to spherical coordinates, how I would do it is I would start with: $$g(r,\phi,\theta) = f(x,y,z)$$ which would mean that $x = x(r,\phi,\theta)$ and so on for y and z and using the formula you provided, I get: $$\frac{\partial}{\partial r} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}$$. Is that right? Or am I misunderstanding the notation?

I made a mistake in the notation, where an extra bar was placed. It should actually read $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{u}^i}=\sum_j\frac{\partial u^j}{\partial \bar{u}^i}\frac{\partial}{\partial u^j}$$
